# Iphone screen doesn't show the title

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Hello i have made a webapplication with angular/ionic but the title doesn't show up on iphones, only on the android phones. I am using ion-title.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons *ngIf="(checkTablet$ | async)" slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>

      <ion-title>Portfolio</ion-title>
    </ion-buttons>

    <ul *ngIf="(checkTablet$ | async) === false">
      <li>
        <h5>Portfolio</h5>
      </li>

      <a routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>
      <a routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active">About</a>
      <a routerLink="/work" routerLinkActive="active">Work</a>
      <a routerLink="/contact" routerLinkActive="active">Contact</a>
    </ul>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: I had the same issue. Had to put the content without  <ion-title>

Comment: @StefaniTotokotsopoulou that was the solution

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's not going to show, you have the ion-title tag inside of the  ion-buttons tag.

Move it outside.

Comment: That is not the problem because the title shows only on android phones. I am using a h2 tag now and it shows also on iPhones

Comment: If it's not a button it shouldn't be in the ion-buttons tag.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).